# Google Play Store Publish error

Tags: android, google-play

I can't change anything now. Its freezed. If I click deactivate on Version 2, it doesnt save changes. Please help.
[image]

Comment: are you being able to move version 4 to prod?

Comment: Nope, I am not able to remove it

Comment: Not remove my friend, move to prod on version 4. Is that button disabled for you? from your screen shot, what I can infer is, version 2 is in prod. Version 3 and 4 are in draft. is that true? please mention what you did to land up in this situation, that should help us.